# Maintain state of react component at each render

Tags: reactjs

I have a "Add" button that renders the same component on each click. The parent state is passed as props to this component which contains fields like email, name etc. Add button can be pressed at max 9 times which means I will generate 9 child components dynamically in a form using "Add" button. I want to maintain the state of all these 9 child components

input type="button" name="numOwners" value="Add"/>

BasicDetails {...this.state}/>

At each click of Add component BasicDetails is rendered

Is it possible using react state?
I am new to React and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use array or object with values of currently existing childrens in parent state and then map these values to render created components. After every 'add' click append item to parent state, so newly created child will appear.

```
  class Parent extends Component {
     state={ items : [] }

   render() {
     return <>
        {this.state.items.map(data => <Child {...data}/>)}
     <\>
     }
  }
```

Comment: should I maintain the parent state as:
this.state = {
 child1:{

 },
 child2:{

 },
 child3:{

 },
 ....
}

and then map using keys of each component

Comment: Yes, you can do this.